# How to make a struct maker like CGRectMake (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, struct, makefile, typedef

i have a struct HLRange with two CGFloat's

```
struct HOLRange
{
CGFloat min;
CGFloat max;
};
typedef struct HOLRange HOLRange;
```

but how do i make a function like HLRangeMake(1,2); .. like CGRectMake?

--EDIT--

my header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct HOLRange
{
    CGFloat min;
    CGFloat max;
};
typedef struct HOLRange HOLRange;

HOLRange HOLRangeMake(CGFloat min, CGFloat max) {
    HOLRange range;
    range.min = min;
    range.max = max;
    return range;
 }

@interface Structs : NSObject {

}

@end


error message: ld: duplicate symbol _HOLRangeMake in             /Users/Documents/projects/iphone/test/catalog/base1/build/base1.build/Debug-iphoneos/base1.build/Objects-normal/armv6/base1AppDelegate.o and /Users/Documents/projects/iphone/test/catalog/base1/build/base1.build/Debug-iphoneos/base1.build/Objects-normal/armv6/main.o
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
HOLRange HLRangeMake(CGFloat min, CGFloat max) {
    HOLRange range;
    range.min = min;
    range.max = max;
    return range;
}
```

Comment: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1, if i add that code

Comment: What's the compiler's error message? Where exactly did you put that code? It must be outside a class implementation. Did you also include a corresponding function declaration in the header file? please edit your question and add more info.

Comment: The linker is complaining about a duplicate symbol because you are importing the header file in more than one other file and this causes the function to be defined multiple times. Put just the function declaration in the header file: `HOLRange HOLRangeMake(CGFloat min, CGFloat max);` and move the function definition into the implementation file.

Comment: To get rid of the duplicate symbol error, you can also use `static inline HOLRange HLRangeMake(CGFloat min, CGFloat max) { ... }` . Actually with this way, you can add the method directly to the pch file and do not need to import headers anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You can see CGRectMake source in CGGeometry.h so you can do the same:

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = width; rect.size.height = height;
  return rect;
}
```

**Edit:** You must either define your function as inline or move its implementation to .m file. You're getting linker errors as you function becomes defined in every compile unit that imports HoleRange.h (?) header.

Answer (score 5):

Old post. However, I'd like to share my method of resolving this problem for future viewers.

```
typdef struct _HOLRange {
    CGFloat min;
    CGFloat max;
} HOLRange;

static inline HOLRange(CGFloat min, CGFloat max) {
    return (HOLRange) {min, max};
}
```

You can define your stuct and Make function like this. Short and quick.

Answer (score 2):

I like the format of this better. It makes more sense visually and seems more "correct."

```
typedef struct {
    CGFloat min;
    CGFloat max;
} HOLRange;

static inline HOLRange HOLRangeMake(CGFloat min, CGFloat max) {
    HOLRange range;
    range.min = min;
    range.max = max;
    return range;
}
```